# Finding possible numbers of Orbits of a group action.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G be a group of order 15. Suppose it acts on a set X of order 4. Can there be only one orbit? Can there be two orbits? If so, provide an example. If not, explain why.

I don’t think there can only be one orbit. As |O1| + ... + |On| = |X| we have that the orbit must have order 4. But by orbit stabilizer theorem, the size of the orbit must divide the size of the group. Hence we have 4 | 15, a contradiction.

I think there can be two orbits. If we have one orbit of size 1 and another of size 3, we run into no contradictions. However, I do not know of any examples. I tried looking at permutations of four points on a plane, but it seems that if if we fix one point (for the orbit of size 1) then there are only 3! possible permutations of the remaining 3 points. Are we allowed to have two groups that behave the same in the action? If so, would a possible example be: for the three points A,B,C, have five instances of swapping A,B, five instances of swapping B,C and five instances of swapping A,C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group $G$ of order $15$ must be cyclic, but $S_4$ has no element of order $15$. So it must be not faithful.

Consider the core, which is a subgroup of $G$. It must be of order $5$ or $15$ because $S_4$ has no element of order $15/3=5$ or $15/1=15$.

If the core is of order $15$, then it is trivial, with four orbits of length $1$.

If the core is of order $5$, then it is equivalent to the action of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ on $X$. Thus we have two orbits of length $3$ and $1$ respectively.

You can also consider it directly by $|O_i|\mid 15$.